# How to quote entrypoint argument when updating a docker service

Tags: bash, docker

I've a small script to update some services in my docker stack.
The problem is that I'm not able to update the entrypoint of a service.
For example, my script generates the following command :

```
docker service update --entrypoint 'go run main.go web' myservice:latest
```

If a run this command in my terminal it works like a charm but when the command is launched by my script I get the following error:

```
invalid argument "'go" for "--entrypoint" flag: EOF found when expecting closing quote
```

Here are the interesting lines in my script :

```
CMD="go run main web"
...
if [ -n "$CMD" ]; then
    update="--entrypoint '${CMD}'"
fi

if [ -n "$update" ]; then
    docker service update $update $fullname
    echo "docker service update $update $fullname" // output => docker service update --entrypoint 'go run main.go web' myservice:latest
fi
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Entrypoint is just the command, args go after the image. `docker run --entrypoint go yourimage:latest run main.go web`

Comment: You can also redesign your Dockerfile to avoid need to override `--entrypoint`, which will simplify this.  Make the Dockerfile `CMD` be a complete command; you can omit `ENTRYPOINT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your script. Using `update` as you are, you are running the following

```
docker service update --entrypoint \'go run main web\'
```

not

```
docker service update --entrypoint 'go run main web'
```

Use an array to store the arguments instead

```
CMD="go run main web"

if [ -n "$CMD" ]; then
    update=(--entrypoint "$CMD")
fi

if [ -n "$update" ]; then  # Really just checks ${update[0]}, but that's sufficient
    docker service update "${update[@]}" "$fullname"
    echo "docker service update ${update[*]} $fullname"
fi
```

Alternatively, you can test `CMD` directly to decide if you want to run the command with the `--entrypoint` option at all.

```
CMD="go run main web"
if [ -n "$CMD" ]; then
    docker service update --entrypoint "$CMD" "$fullname"
    echo "docker service --entrypoint $CMD $fullname"
fi
```

Comment: I like the last suggestion. I doesn't require an array, just proper quoting, which is what I was going to post as an answer. :)

Comment: Thank you @chepner.
I needed an array as I can have multiple update options. 
Now my script run correctly. 
Thank you again ;-)